# Import error 'It seems your QField project was not set to offline editing'

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync, importerror

It was my first time using QField for a survey project and I hadn't realised that when I configured my QField package I should have set it to 'offline editing' instead of 'copy'. I have now collected all my data but I can't import it into QGIS. Is there any way around this or will I manually have to remap and add attribute information to QGIS?